# iPad app doesn't display correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, ipad

I don't know how to describe, but you can see it in the screenshots. These are in vertical view:

[image]

[image]

These below are in horizontal view:

[image]

[image]

Usually it works normally, but this time it went wrong. I removed it from the multitask and then it works correctly again.

- App Version: 1.4.0.234
- Device: iPad2,2
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

Comment: Do you have the latest version? Think there was such a bug some time ago that was fixed.

Comment: Yes, the latest one

Comment: What app version and iOS version are you running? Does restarting the app fix it?  Does the app work normally to a point and then break?

Comment: @BrianNickel added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this issue doesn't happen regularly, I'm going to chalk this up to one of the myriad orientation problems with iOS8. For whatever reason, a single window in an application will get out of synch with the device orientation and will stay that way until the app terminates.  This usually manifests with the [keyboard out of sync but can happen with other windows as well](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+8+orientation+bug&safe=active&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1326&bih=1160&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIqobzppiQyAIVRjaICh0G2QEA).

I don't think there's anything we can do, but if it keeps happening I can take a look.

Comment: [is this the problem?](http://blog.lessfun.com/images/2014/09/lessfun_ios8_adapt_keyboard.png)